# C# add data to SQL Server if it doesn't exist, if exist update count

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having a little bit of a problem with this code. I'm trying to make a code that reads a text from textbox and adds words to database word by word. If word already exist in database, it should increase the number of count that word was added to database, if word doesn't exist, it should add the to database.

Everything is working fine on its own perfectly, but when I input words that exist in database and new words at the same time problem occurs. Code increases count number for existing words as it should, but simply doesn't add new words to the database. And I'm not getting any error.

How to make sure that both functions work at the same for new and old words?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
con.Open();

if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    string raw = rawtxt.Text.ToString();
    string[] rawwords = raw.Split(' ');

    foreach (var rawword in rawwords)
    {
        string mon_s = "Select * From Dict";
        SqlCommand mon_search = new SqlCommand(mon_s, con);
        SqlDataReader srd = mon_search.ExecuteReader();

        while (srd.Read())
        {
            if (srd[1].ToString() == rawword)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        srd.Close();

        if (flag == false)
        {
            string raw_lat_c = rawword.Replace("а", "a").Replace("б", "b").Replace("в", "v").Replace("г", "g").Replace("д", "d").Replace("е", "e").Replace("ё", "e").Replace("ж", "j").Replace("з", "z").Replace("и", "i").Replace("й", "i").Replace("к", "k").Replace("л", "l").Replace("м", "m").Replace("н", "n").Replace("о", "o").Replace("ө", "u").Replace("п", "p").Replace("р", "r").Replace("с", "s").Replace("т", "t").Replace("у", "u").Replace("ү", "u").Replace("ф", "f").Replace("х", "h").Replace("ц", "ts").Replace("ч", "ch").Replace("ш", "sh").Replace("щ", "sh").Replace("ъ", "i").Replace("ы", "i").Replace("ь", "i").Replace("э", "e").Replace("ю", "yu").Replace("я", "ya");

            int count = 1;

            string ins = "Insert into Dict (mongol, latin, count) values(N'" + rawword + "','"+ raw_lat_c +"', '" + count + "')";                      

            SqlCommand command_ins = new SqlCommand(ins, con);
            command_ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        if (flag == true)
        {
            string upd_count = "Update Dict Set count=count+1 Where mongol=N'" + rawword + "'";
            SqlCommand command_upcnt = new SqlCommand(upd_count, con);
            command_upcnt.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Your `flag` will never become false if it was set to true once. Before `while (srd.Read())` set your flag to false;

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the value of "flag" in every foreach statement. So, before the while, you should do add `SqlDataReader srd = mon_search.ExecuteReader();` - like this:

```
[...]
SqlDataReader srd = mon_search.ExecuteReader();

flag = false;
while (srd.Read())
{
    if (srd[1].ToString() == rawword)
    {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
[...]
```

What you are doing now is that once one word in "rawwords" is found in your database, all the remaining words will always be "repeated" because your flag will neve be false.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like This

```
 if (srd[1].ToString() == rawword)
 {
       flag = true;
       break;
 }
 else
 {
       flag = false;
 }
```